# How to get a list of cities in a country from database?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have 2 models, City and Country. I want to show cities in the country on a page based on the country selected. I tried to query the Country model passing it to the City model to find all cities related to the country but currently, pages show all cities no matter what is the country.

How I can show cities in one country when the user selects the country from the page?

Any help or suggestions are highly appreciated.

**models.py**

```
class City(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey('Country', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='country')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=90, verbose_name='City name')
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('city:cities', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

     def save(self, *args, **kwargs): 
         if not self.slug:
             self.slug = slugify(self.name)
         return super().save(*args, **kwargs)

class Country(models.Model):
    country_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Country name',unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.country_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
       return reverse('city:cities', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs): 
         if not self.slug:
             self.slug = slugify(self.country_name)
         return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**views.py**

```
class CountriesListView(ListView):
    template_name = "countries.html"
    model = Country

    context_object_name = "countries"

class CitiesListView(ListView):
    template_name = "cities_list.html"
    model = City

    context_object_name = "cities"

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(CitiesListView, self).get_context_data(*args,**kwargs)
        countries = Country.objects.all()
        cities = City.objects.filter(country__in=countries)
        context['cities'] = cities
        return context
```

**templates**

```
# countries.html

<h1>Countries</h1>

{% for country in countries %}
  <h3><a href="{% url 'city:cities' country.slug %}">{{ country.country_name }}</h3>
{% endfor %}


# cities_list.html

<h1>Cities</h1>

{% for city in cities %}
  <div>
        <h3><a href="{% url 'city:details' city.slug %}">{{ city }}</a></h3>
  </div>  
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I suggest you to use Ajax for such of things

Comment: Thank you, Florin. Can you tell how to use or where to look at how to use Ajax for that?

Answer (score 4):

The [**`related_name=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) is the name of the relation in *reverse*, so to access the `City` objects of a specific `Country`. Therefore naming it `Country` is *not* a good idea. You can rename it to `cities` for example:

```
class City(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(
        'Country',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='cities'
    )
    # …
```

You can use a `DetailView` to render a single `Country`, so:

```
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView

class CountryDetailView(DetailView):
    template_name = 'country_detail.html'
    model = Country
    context_object_name = 'country'
```

In the urls, you can thus register this view under the name `cities` with a slug field:

```
# app/urls.py

from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name='city'

urlpatterns = [
    # …,
    path(
        'country/<slug:slug>',
        views.CountryDetailView.as_view(),
        name='cities'
    ),
]
```

In the template, you can then access the relation in reverse:

```
<!-- country_detail.html -->

{{ country }}

{% for city in country.cities.all %}
    {{ city }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I tried it in many ways, but it's not showing only one country with cities in it or not behaving as expected. I am getting back <QuerySet [<Country: Estonia>, <Country: Mexico>, <Country: France>]> from {{ country }} and nothing from the second part, the for loop. If I remove .cities.all then I get list of countries. What do I miss?

Comment: @EgonSaks: but did you use a `DetailView`, with as parameter the `slug`?

Comment: Yes, Willem. In the URL I use it with the slug, as you mentioned. /country/Estonia and then what I see is the  QuerySet from {{ country }} and nothing comes from for loop. If I remove .cities.all I can get a list of countries instead of a list of cities belonging to Estonia by example.

Comment: I tried to access it through shell then it works like that:
>>> from city.models import City, Country
>>> countries  = Country.objects.all()
>>> cities = countries.cities.all
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'cities'
>>> cities = countries[0].cities.all()
>>> cities
<QuerySet [<City: Tallinn>]>

Comment: @EgonSaks: but `country` is a *single* `Country`, so `countries` indeed works. If you want to do it per `country` in the template, you can thus iterate it with `{% for country in countries %}` and then `{% for city in country.cities.all %}`.

Comment: Now shows all cities, but not distinguishing what belongs to that country. For example, country/Estonia should show only Tallinn, but currently, it shows Tallinn, Mexico City, Paris.

Comment: I am using Postgresql as database, hope it's not related to some limitations or differences on Postgresql how to retrieve data from the database.

Comment: @EgonSaks: sorry, I made a mistake. It should be a subclass of `DetailView`, not of `ListView` :s.

Comment: Yes, I am triggering the DetailView. I added to DetailView: 

def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args,**kwargs)
        context['now'] = timezone.now()
        return context

And getting to template:

<h1>DetailView</h1>
Date: Aug. 31, 2020

<QuerySet [<Country: Estonia>, <Country: Mexico>, <Country: France>]>
Tallinn
Mexico City
Paris

Comment: @EgonSaks: yes, but I made a mistake, it should be a subclass of `DetailView`, not `ListView`. Then the template should be as is in the answer.

Comment: Now it works!! Thanks a lot, Willem. I was trying to figure it out like 3 days and now it really works. Thanks a lot for your help!!! :)